# How do i show this :$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\sigma_{2k+1}(n)}{\sigma_{2k-1}(n)}=n²$ if it is true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

I run some computation in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sigma_11%2816%29%29%2F%28sigma_9%2816%29%29) I find for many fixed values of $n$ and for an arbitrary integer $k$ the ratio :

$\frac{\sigma_{2k+1}(n)}{\sigma_{2k-1}(n)}$ close to $n²$ .

My question here : How do i show that  :

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sigma_{2k+1}(n)}{\sigma_{2k-1}(n)}=n²$$

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: hint : $\sigma_k(n)$ is multiplicative, this means that $\sigma_k(m n) = \sigma_k(m)\sigma_k(n)$ whenever $gcd(m,n) = 1$, so if you prove it for $n = p^N$ you'll get that it is true for every $n$

Comment: That is the problem , how do you can prove it for n=p^n, I think it is easy to only to show it for n=pq

Comment: you don't know what are the divisors of $p^n$  ??? ok, so $\sigma_k(p^n)$ has a simple formula, and your limit is easy to prove

Comment: you can prove much stronger than that : if $k\geq k'\geq 1$ then : $$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sigma_{k}(n)}{\sigma_{k'}(n)}=n^{k-k'}$$